# AttributeError: 'RFECV' object has no attribute 'grid_scores_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, attributeerror, feature-selection

## Problem I faced:

Getting this error continuously **AttributeError: 'RFECV' object has no attribute 'grid_scores_'**. The code is given below:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=101)
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=rfc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(5), scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Optimal number of features: {}'.format(rfecv.n_features_))

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
plt.title('Recursive Feature Elimination with Cross-Validation', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold', pad=20)
plt.xlabel('Number of features selected', fontsize=14, labelpad=20)
plt.ylabel('% Correct Classification', fontsize=14, labelpad=20)
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_, color='#303F9F', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

**Errors are:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 5
      3 plt.xlabel('Number of features selected', fontsize=14, labelpad=20)
      4 plt.ylabel('% Correct Classification', fontsize=14, labelpad=20)
----> 5 plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_, color='#303F9F', linewidth=3)
      6 plt.show()

AttributeError: 'RFECV' object has no attribute 'grid_scores_'
```

## Things I tried

I tried replacing **grid_scores_** with **cv_results_** as someone recommended in Quora, but it pops up with a new error. As per the documentation on sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV, there is no attribute like **grid_scores_**, but the code I am using to learn contains this attribute.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
plt.title('Recursive Feature Elimination with Cross-Validation', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold', pad=20)
plt.xlabel('Number of features selected', fontsize=14, labelpad=20)
plt.ylabel('% Correct Classification', fontsize=14, labelpad=20)
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_, color='#303F9F', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

**Errors are:**

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 5
      3 plt.xlabel('Number of features selected', fontsize=14, labelpad=20)
      4 plt.ylabel('% Correct Classification', fontsize=14, labelpad=20)
----> 5 plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.cv_results_) + 1), rfecv.cv_results_, color='#303F9F', linewidth=3)
      6 plt.show()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2812, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2810 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2811 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2812     return gca().plot(
   2813         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2814         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1688, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445 """
   1446 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1447 
   (...)
   1685 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1686 """
   1687 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1688 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1689 for line in lines:
   1690     self.add_line(line)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:311, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    309     this += args[0],
    310     args = args[1:]
--> 311 yield from self._plot_args(
    312     this, kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey=ambiguous_fmt_datakey)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:501, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey)
    499     self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
    500 if self.axes.yaxis is not None:
--> 501     self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    503 if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    504     raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    505                      f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:1675, in Axis.update_units(self, data)
   1673 neednew = self.converter != converter
   1674 self.converter = converter
-> 1675 default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
   1676 if default is not None and self.units is None:
   1677     self.set_units(default)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py:105, in StrCategoryConverter.default_units(data, axis)
    103 # the conversion call stack is default_units -> axis_info -> convert
    104 if axis.units is None:
--> 105     axis.set_units(UnitData(data))
    106 else:
    107     axis.units.update(data)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py:181, in UnitData.__init__(self, data)
    179 self._counter = itertools.count()
    180 if data is not None:
--> 181     self.update(data)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py:214, in UnitData.update(self, data)
    212 # check if convertible to number:
    213 convertible = True
--> 214 for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data):
    215     # OrderedDict just iterates over unique values in data.
    216     _api.check_isinstance((str, bytes), value=val)
    217     if convertible:
    218         # this will only be called so long as convertible is True.

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: What is your `scikit-learn` version?

Comment: You've essentially asked two questions. The answer to the first has been provided (and you alluded to it already in the question). The answer to the second is just that you can't plot a dictionary; decide _what_ information you want to plot, and extract that from the `cv_results_` dictionary first.

Answer (score 0):

The `grid_scores_` function has been [deprecated](https://scikit-learn.org/1.1/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.grid_scores_) by `scikit-learn` from version `1.2.2`. However, if you really need to use it, you need to uninstall your current `scikit-learn` version by the following:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn # if you are using pip
conda uninstall scikit-learn # if you are using conda
```

and then install the older version by:

```
pip install scikit-learn==1.1.3 # if you are using pip
conda install scikit-learn==1.1.3 # if you are using conda
```

Once the installation is done, you can check whether you installed your desired version by:

```
pip show scikit-learn # if you are using pip
conda list scikit-learn # if you are using conda
```

Comment: followed the steps mentioned above, still getting the same error message on line: `print('Selected features: %s' % list(X.columns[rfecv.support_]))` 
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"]) + 1), rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"], color='#303F9F', linewidth=3)
```